# What is the preferred way to add Codable support to existing framework enums?

Tags: swift, enums

There are numerous `enums` in AppKit and UIKit that do not adopt `Codable`. What is the preferred way to add `Codable` support to those `enums` such that there isn't a problem in the future should Apple make them `Codable`?

For example:

```
struct Preferences : Codable { 
  var timeFormat : DateFormatter.Style
  var dateFormat : DateFormatter.Style
}
```

DateFormatter.Style is defined as follows:

```
public enum Style : UInt {
    case none
    case short
    case medium
    case long
    case full
}
```

One could just use an extension as such:

```
extension DateFormatter.Style : Codable {}
```

But what happens if Apple decides to add `Codable` in a future version? Is it better practice to just make my own `enum` that mirrors `DateFormatter` and thus has independent support for `Codable`?

```
enum MyDateStyle : Int, Codable {
    case none
    case short
    case medium
    case long
    case full

    var asNSDateFormatterStyle : DateFormatter.Style { 
      switch (self) {
        case .none:  return .none
        case .short: return .short
        // ... snip ...
      }
    }

}
```

For one or two `enums` creating a mirroring implementation isn't too bad, but for much more it's rather tedious, especially if the enum in question has numerous cases.

*macOS 10.15, Xcode 11b6*

Comment: Or you can store the raw value instead in your struct.

Comment: Since Apple hasn't explicitly assigned raw values to many of these enums, aren't they free to reorder them? If so, then wouldn't that break any apps that stored rawValues as the rawValues could change if Apple reordered things or added additional cases not at the bottom. (Probably unlikely for things in AppKit...)

Comment: I guess if they do any Codable implementations will break as well. Persisting enum values is always error prone I suppose.